# How to declare a function that returns value and has parameters x86 assembly MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm trying to declare a function using `PROC` and so far this does not work:

```
inputArray(lpIntegerArray:dword,lpStrNum:dword,lpStrPrompt:dword):dword PROC
```

and neither does this

```
inputArray PROC lpIntegerArray:dword,lpStrNum:dword,lpStrPrompt:dword:dword
```

How do I declare a function in x86 assembly MASM that takes parameters **and** returns a dword value?

I'm using `.model flat`

Comment: The return type isn't specified in the `PROC` directive. You simply put whatever you want to return in `EAX` (or the appropriate register(s) for the ABI used) prior to your `RET`, and let the caller interpret that value.

Comment: I removed all of the parameters and just put `inputArray PROC` and that works, but whenever I just remove the trailing `:dword` I get an error that says: "language type must be specified"

Comment: Specify the language type (`C` or `STDCALL`) either in the `.MODEL` directive (e.g. `.MODEL FLAT,C`), or in the `PROC` directive before the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Chisx, if you really like astronomy, I can tell you that assembler language is another planet, different to any other. Next code is a little 8086 assembler program with Intel syntax that has one function to calculate factorial, gets one parameter from SI register and returns the value in AX register (made with EMU8086) :

```
.stack 100h
.data
.code          
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax,@data
  mov  ds,ax

  mov  si, 5 ;PARAMETER FOR FUNCTION.                                         
  call non_recursive_factorial ;RESULTS RETURNS IN AX.

;FINISH PROGRAM PROPERLY.  
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h           
;-----------------------------------------
;FUNCTION TO CALCULATE FACTORIAL.
;PARAMETER : SI.
;RETURNS   : AX.
proc non_recursive_factorial
  mov  cx,2 ;SECOND NUMBER TO MULTIPLY.
  mov  ax,1 ;FIRST NUMBER TO MULTIPLY.
while:                                  
  mul  cx ;AX*CX = DX:AX.
  inc  cx ;NEXT NUMBER TO MULTIPLY.
  cmp  cx, si ;PARAMETER BEEN USED.
  jbe  while
  ret
endp
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. Hope it helps.